# How can I fix an android tablet which says data wipe error

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, factory-reset, boot-loop, tablet

My tablet seems to have have got stuck when trying to reset it to factory settings after it got stuck in the boot loop. It keeps telling me "error, data wipe failed", then flashes something with regards to s.d card. Sometimes it comes up with the menu but won't let me click on anything?

Comment: not sure if I have used correct tag?!

Comment: I think you should provide more info regarding tablet brand, model no and what does it flashes? Try to be more specific to let our expert users to dive into specific solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enter Recovery Mode and factory reset again from there.

To enter recovery mode, power off your phone and press and hold the power button along with the volume down button. The Recovery Mode menu should appear and there should be an option to do a factory reset.

See [here](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-boot-to-recovery/) for more info on how to enter Recovery Mode.